# Anchor tag as button without href

Tags: html, css

I find unless on a form, `<a>` anchor tags are almost always used as buttons.

My question is not why the `<a>` tag is used, but rather why `href="#"` is used also.

To my understanding, `<a>` without an href is valid html and, in fact, offers more differentiation between a "button" anchor and link anchor tag, as `:link` and `:visited` are only triggered if there is an href. Even the cursor can be changed back to a pointer, and the text being highlight problem by changing the `::selection`. ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/gX7MJ/2/))

While both are effected by `:active` (although even that can be differentiated by saying `a:visited:active, a:link:active {---}` for links), the only reason I can think of not to do this is the tabbing order is also removed.

However, on the plus side, you get to remove `href="#"` (which can be useful when testing a page, javascript is disabled, etc), give a different default style to a 'button', and is easier to differentiate in code. Also, you could always assign it `tabindex="0"` to put it back into the tab flow, and in the future css may introduce [nav-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#nav-index0), which is already introduced in Opera (although this is a property at risk).

While removing tab order can be a hassle, I consider it as such: your simply replacing `href="#"` for `tabindex="0"`, which still differentiates between a "button" and a link, allowing you to also style them.

So I guess my original question of why `href="#"` is used is still my main focus, but would like to hear if I missed any points of interest in why should/shouldn't be done to potentially be a better way to separate links from "buttons".

Comment: Anchor tags aren't needed any more. Just give an element an ID, and you can use it as an anchor.

Comment: @arxanas: Yea, I hear HTML6 is dropping all elements except `div`. It's really going to revolutionize web development.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Who needs all those new pesky tags anyways? To darn useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute `href="#"` is used because some (really) old browsers supported attributes like `onclick` for links only. By using `href="#"`, you turned an `a` element to a link in this sense. Later, the original reasons were forgotten, and people just copied code.

When JavaScript is disabled in the browser, the `href="#"` attribute makes the element a link to the start of the current document. This is almost never a reasonable fallback; to provide non-JavaScript fallback, the `href` attribute should point to a URL that contains some server-side fallback.

When JavaScript is enabled and the author has forgotten to end an event handler with `return false` or something else that suppresses normal link processing, the link is followed after execution of the handler. So the current page is reloaded and positioned at the start. This may or may not go unnoticed.

Comment: By really old, do you mean not in use anymore (or extremely uncommon)? And by server-side fallback, do you mean like (perhaps) a php file that would do the same thing, even though the page would change? While this is not always possible, I can this see the purpose for this.

Comment: By really old, I mean something like Netscape 4. By server-side fallback, I indeed mean (for example) a php file that somehow duplicates the functionality of the JavaScript code. It’s not always possible, or feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Giving anchor tag buttons an href with something like "#screen1", "#screen2", etc and coupling it with some sort of routing or url matching allows your application to take advantage of the browser's back and forward buttons.

If clicking on #screen1, then clicking on #screen2, then being able to use the back button to get to screen1 is useful for your app, you may want to use the hrefs in this way.

Comment: I'm am asking how to use them as buttons, not links. In other words, I'm asking if an href value should be used at all / not using would cause problems.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.containerstore.com/elfa/designCenter/index.htm  the buttons on the left are anchor tags with hrefs, using back and forward will move you through your previously opened menus.